# packagekitd takes a lot of CPU when starting Loki

Tags: package-management, cpu

I have a loud fan and don't like when CPU goes hot for no reason.

When I start Loki 25% of CPU is taken by `packagekitd` which is enough to make the fan too loud. Anyway, I expect that to check for updates and go off quickly, but instead it keeps running. I can kill it manually but that's not the way to go.

After killing it and searching manually for updates (AppCenter/Updates), `packagekitd` starts again, and then it doesn't stress the CPU at all and also closes very quickly after having searched for updates.

What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known issue, it's reported and confirmed here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1587975

I'm still waiting for an fix or update myself.

Comment: It's amazing this bug is almost a year old. I wonder how many kilowatts and barrels of oil this bug has consumed.