# packagekitd workaround?

Tags: release-loki

I am new to elementary OS and have basic linux knowledge. Anyway, I have gathered that packagekitd resource consumption is a known issue which is caused by unsigned PPAs. I do have them.

I was thinking what would be the best way to continue. Should I remove them and not use them - which will be kind of a hassle. Is there anything else I can do ?

Currently I just kill it manually.

Also, how do I exactly remove them if thats the way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a reported bug](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/packagekitd-takes-a-lot-of-cpu-when-starting-loki). Anyway, I commented the associated file (specifically, i had this problem with Acestream), as found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, but if you also have the habit of updating manually your package database, you can disable the automatic update by changing `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` to `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`